# Chrome Extensions - How can I keep a log of events that happened either on a content script or background script?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I basically want to keep a log of the date and time when something happens.
That event can happen either on a content or background script, it doesn't matter, because I can change it if it's easier on one or the other.

If I use console.log, the logs are lost if the browser is closed.

I thought about creating an extra html file in my extension and to write the logs there, but I don't know how to do it.

Any advice? How do I write into that html file *from* the content or background script? I think I don't know some fundamental stuff that prevents me from doing it, or I may be approaching this in the wrong way...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: (1) How big do you anticipate this log will be over time (~disk space/number of entries) (2) how long will you keep the log entries in terms of time (days, months, years) and when (if ever) should the log be cleared? (3) is the intent to write to logs and never/rarely read them -or- do you want to create a read/write implementation to possibly display log entries to user? Your choice of implementation depends on these considerations.

Comment: @Neea thanks for the answer!
(1) I estimate it would be 1 entry to the log per day, maybe 3 maximum per day.
(2) I think 1 month would be a reasonable time to keep the logs. Or maybe 2 weeks as a minimum.
(3) The intent is to read them, yes. I have to monitor these events and see how often they occur.